# redirecting to author page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i need to redirect visitors who are coming from a certain url "http://www.example.com/wp-includes/qp2qp-sktcho/" tho their author page in wordpress "http://www.example.com/author/username" and i am using this code in one of the theme files

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.example.com/wp-includes/qp2qp-sktcho/" && is_user_logged_in()){
       $targetUrl = get_author_posts_url($user->user_nicename );
       wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
add_action('pre_get_posts','wh_post_display_order_view');
       exit;
   }
}
```

but instead of redirecting to "http://www.example.com/author/username"
it makes the redirection to "http://www.example.com/author/"

do you know what is worng with the code?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `get_author_posts_url($user->user_nicename );` with  `get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) );`

Please check dumping the function output with

> var_dump();

to make sure if it is returning correct url. Later, then remove var_dump();

Please also check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

Answer (score 0):

Change your get_author_posts_url to below:

```
get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
```

More details check here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url